# How to properly handle loading and partial states when executing a GraphQL query using ApolloClient?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm working on a backend application that gathers data from GraphQL endpoints and I'm using `ApolloClient` to do so:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: uri,
    link: new HttpLink({ uri: uri, fetch }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false,
    }),
});
```

When I use the `query` function:

```
client.query({
    query: query,
    variables: vars,
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
})
```

it returns an `ApolloQueryResult` object:

```
ApolloQueryResult<T> = {
    data: T;
    errors?: ReadonlyArray<GraphQLError>;
    error?: ApolloError;
    loading: boolean;
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
    partial?: boolean;
}
```

My problem is that I've checked the docs and it doesn't say how I should handle `loading` and `partial` states. I'm not using React and I have the impression that these are only used for frontend calls, but I want to be sure.

I tested it and `partial` and `loading` is always `undefined` for me, no matter what endpoint I call.

What is the proper way to handle these from node? Can it happen that these are not `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been curious about this myself, so I had a look at the source.

`loading`: [can ignore] The `query` method you are calling on [ApolloClient](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/src/core/ApolloClient.ts) never sets `result.loading` to true.  The front-end React [useQuery hook](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/src/react/hooks/useQuery.ts) does, which makes sense because its job is to help with the UI renders.

`partial`: [depends] The `ApolloQueryResult` [typedef source](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/e0732df6dddceb2fa6b2c9c6a1d7b5454608bd41/src/core/types.ts#L135) includes the following comment:  "*If result.data was read from the cache with missing fields, result.partial will be true...*".  You client is configured to use a cache, but the query has a `no-cache` policy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Bowman. What should I do if I use a cache? What does the `partial` state mean? Do I have to re-request it? I'm a bit disappointed though. I used libs with cache features on other platforms and as a user I shouldn't know about cache misses / evictions / etc **at all**. It should be seamlessly handled behind the scenes.

Comment: Glad to help.  `partial` tells the caller that some, but not all of the requested data can be delivered from cache in case of network error.  This is a very handy front-end feature where unreliable networking is a constant headache.  Apps have the option of rendering partial data in the UI right away, while flagging it to the user incomplete and retrying.  Less relevant for backend services like yours, though, you are right.